# StackOverflowError on ViewModel initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I met with strange problem during my ViewModel class initialization. I suppose that code is the best way to explain problem.

My all ViewModels are inherit after this:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    internal var args: Bundle? = null
}
```

I have delegate to provide ViewModel to fragment, which automaticaly load arguments from fragment.

```
interface ViewModelFactoryProvider<VIEW_MODEL : BaseViewModel, BINDING : ViewDataBinding> : ReadOnlyProperty<ViewModelFragment<VIEW_MODEL, BINDING>, VIEW_MODEL> {

val viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

override fun getValue(thisRef: ViewModelFragment<VIEW_MODEL, BINDING>, property: KProperty<*>): VIEW_MODEL {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(thisRef, viewModelFactory).get(thisRef.viewModelClass).apply {
        thisRef.arguments?.let { thisRef.viewModel.args = it }
    }
  }
}
```

Base fragment implement interface above and create view model this way:

```
class ViewModelFragment<VIEW_MODEL : BaseViewModel, BINDING : ViewDataBinding> : Fragment(), ViewModelFactoryProvider<VIEW_MODEL, BINDING>{

    @Inject
    override lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    val viewModel: VIEW_MODEL by this
}
```

All works great until fragment with my ViewModel don't have any additional arguments, otherwise I get:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getContext(Fragment.java:683)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getViewModelStore(Fragment.java:327)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStores.of(ViewModelStores.java:60)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(ViewModelProviders.java:104)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:15)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$DefaultImpls.getValue(ViewModelFactoryProvider.kt:16)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getValue(ViewModelFragment.kt:20)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.ViewModelFragment.getViewModel(ViewModelFragment.kt)
    at pl.kulbaka.karol.unilang.tools.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryProvider$
```

For now I have no idea where I can search for circle dependency and what is the reason of it. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by accessing `thisRef.viewModel` while calculating it's value in the delegate

You delegate the `viewModel` property via `by this`. I.e. the method `getViewModel()` uses the `override fun getValue(..)` method of the delegate which in turn calls `getViewModel()` in `thisRef.viewModel.args = it`. The circle restarts at that point.

What you want is roughly

```
override fun getValue(thisRef: ViewModelFragment<VIEW_MODEL, BINDING>, property: KProperty<*>): VIEW_MODEL {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(thisRef, viewModelFactory).get(thisRef.viewModelClass).apply {
        thisRef.arguments?.let { this.args = it }
    }
  }
}
```

which sets the arguments not on the property it's trying to create but on the `ViewModel` returned from `ViewModelProviders.of(...).get(...)`

Comment: Is there any way to set up viewModel before it will be passed to the fragment? I want to pass fragment arguments to viewmodel implicitly.

Comment: @KarolKulbaka Your (fixed) code does that, no? There is also an actual factory for viewmodels that you can override to do desired preparations of viewmodels: https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/android-viewmodel-and-factoryprovider-good-way-to-manage-it-with-dagger-2-d9e20a07084c

Comment: I didn't catch resolution at first look. It works perfectly ;)